# Use terminal to get Mac battery manufacture date/age

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, bash, battery

How do I get the manufacture date or age like what's shown in CoconutBattery using the terminal? I tried `ioreg -cr AppleSmartBattery` which gave a `ManufacturerData` (data, not date, but it was a date format) that's way too old to be correct for my computer. `system_profiler SPPowerDataType` doesn't show anything related to what I want.

EDIT: there is a ManufactureDate line in ioreg, but it's a 5 digit number – how do I decode that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Smart Battery Data spec](http://sbs-forum.org/specs/sbdat110.pdf), the `ManufactureDate` is as follows:

> The date is packed in the following fashion: (year-1980) * 512 + month * 32 + day

More specifically, when the integer is converted to binary:

```
bits 0-4  -- day
bits 5-8 -- month
bits 9-15 -- years since 1980
```

Verifying this using my own machine, the integer derives to something like 2018-x-x, which makes sense given the age of my laptop.

( On Big Sur with my work laptop, however, the value is no longer a small integer, so I'm not sure how the latest OS is encoding the date information )

Comment: I think I'm not converting it right. Is there a bash/JS command that can do it?

Comment: (I know the 5 digits are correct, having put the date in coconut battery into that formula)

Comment: You can bitwise shift and mask in bash I believe.  My bitwise operations are rusty but something like: `echo $((1980+(0x7f & $d>>9)))-$((0x0f & ($d>>5)))-$((0x1f & $d))`, where $d is the integer.  Or you can just follow the packing formula -- take the integer, divide by 512, record the year, subtract it from the integer...

Comment: That bash line gave me a syntax error, but it's ok since I was able to modify it to use in JavaScript.